# CSS not applied in IE10 when using attributes added via jQuery 1.11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to style a multi-level menu using aria attributes that are added via jQuery.

```
.js-menubar [role="menu"] {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.js-menubar [role="menu"][aria-hidden="false"] { 
    display: block; 
}

.js-menubar [role="menu"][aria-hidden="true"] { 
    display: none; 
}
```

It works in all browsers except for IE 10. In IE 10, CSS is not applied to 2nd and 3rd level list until I hover over it.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doZBap

Switching from jQuery v1.11 to v2 fixes the issue, but I have to stick with v1.11 for IE 8 compatibility.

Comment: force some layout after